# Socket wiring to relay + Ardunio / Pi

Tags: arduino, relay, raspberry-pi, mains, plug

I’m working on a personal project at the moment and needed a small amount of electronics help. What I am building is a RaspberryPi/Arduino connected to wall plugs (which is not being fitted to the wall but rather attached to a Pattress box and will be used like a bulky power strip).

The RPi is connected (5v) to a relay (rated 250v 10a) and runs a dumb node server (this end is my specialty) that controls the relay. I am going to use twillio so that you can SMS the plug a command such as -

“Brew coffee for 10 minutes”

This will then turn the relay on for just 10 min. The issue I have is with the confidence of my electronics. If you feel you could help please could you take a look at the schematic below -

[image: Schematic]

Comment: 1)Are you connecting Rpi with relay or arduino                  2)where is the power to the relay board(you have given only +5V,Gnd and signal from arduino)

Comment: 1) Arduino for now will be switched out with the RPi later on. No issues wiring this its just the mains I am unsure about.

Comment: 2) Power to relay is working with current wiring as shown above

Comment: mains connection is correct

Comment: It might help if you post a link to the manual for that relay board so people can give better advice.

Answer (score 3):

The relay module shown appears to be the [Sainsmart 4 channel relay module](http://www.sainsmart.com/4-channel-5v-relay-module-for-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino-msp430-ttl-logic.html), or similar.

If this is so, the [SainSmart documentation](http://www.thesunrain.com/Amazon/4%20relay%20board/4-ch%20relay%20module.pdf) shows the relay connections on the screw terminals:

[image: Relay]

The following connections would work - The neutral connections are optional, I prefer to disconnect both live and neutral of my appliances when I am experimenting.

[image: Relay connection]

Alternatively, a [DPDT type relay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Two-DPDT-Signal-Relays-Module-Board-5V-for-MCU-Project-/130645629860?pt=Vintage_Electronics_R2&hash=item1e6b161ba4) switches two sets of contacts per relay, so both live and neutral can be connected through, or disconnected, with a single control signal from the microcontroller for each relay:

[image: DPDT Relay]

**Note:**

The Raspberry Pi will not be able to work with a relay board that expects a 5 Volt control signal. The RPi outputs **3.3 Volts** on its GPIOs. One needs to ensure that the relay board being used can deal with the lower signal and supply voltages.

Comment: Huge help thank you. I now have it all working (with the RPi as well) It has been running fine all day off the single +5 v and 3.3 on the control signal :)

I now have it wired up as a REST interface, Twillio (for sms) and and Alfred (for osx) workflow... looking forward to adding geolocation support.

Comment: @adambutler if you've shared more of your project, would appreciate learning more about it.  I'm working on something similar - a coffee robot - at the moment.